# Integrating googlefonts in Ruby on Rails 3.2 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, google-font-api

I have to use fonts form Google in one Rails application . The ordinary HTML code defines googlefonts usage like this :

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I tried to add the same line in my alpplication.html.erb , but it didn't work . Then I extracted the @font-face definitions (from the location pointed by link-href) into a separate css.scss file and included the file in my manifest css file :

```
#googlefonts.css.scss
@font-face {
font-family: 'PT Sans';
font-style: italic;
font-weight: 400;
src: local('PT Sans Italic'), local('PTSans-Italic'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ptsans/v4/xxxx.woff) format('woff');
```

}

```
#application.css

   *= require googlefonts
   *= require_tree .
```

It did not happen again.

Please, help me solve the puzzle. What is the best practice of using fonts, hosted in Google in Rails 3 application ?

EDIT : Here is my css, referring to @font-face definition :

```
#styles.css.scss
body{
font-family: "PT Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
line-height:25px;
text-shadow:none !important;
color:#444;
}
```

Comment: Please add the CSS selector where you are using 'PT Sans'

Comment: Thank you for the attention , I edited my question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the problem :

Refinery has partial for head section , located in refinery/ dir. The format of this partial is .erb (default) . My application.html is .haml format . When I converted the _head.thml.erb to _head.html.haml , it worked nicely . Setting google fonts is simple , just like Stephenmurdoch described in his answer .

Answer (score 4):

Using your example code, the following works just fine for me:

```
# stick this inside the head section of application.html.erb 
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

# stick this in your css file:
body{
  font-family: "PT Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

That's all you need, it works just fine. I'd suggest ditching the googlefonts.css.scss file unless you've got local copies of your font that you want to serve. The link google provide you with actually handle that code for you anyway, [see for yourself](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic)

Comment: Thank you for your time . It's very strange , I've just created a new Rails app , following your instructions , and it works perfectly . In my Refinery CMS app , which caused problems , it still does not work. What could be wrong ?

Comment: hi, have you removed the css file as well as the reference to it? You need to actually delete the file as require tree will cause it to be included. AFAIK refinery should work well with google fonts..

Comment: I think I've found the problem : Refinery have separated partial for head section , located in refinery/ dir. The format of this partial is .erb (default) . My application.html is .haml format . When I converted the _head.thml.erb to _head.html.haml , it worked nicely . Thank you for your assistance , I was lost in the fog ... Do you think I should create an answer?